# Unable to cast CODE FIRST

Tags: ef-code-first

```
public void Register(User user)
    {
        context.Users.Add(user);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[Forum.Model.User]' to type 'Forum.Model.User'.

Error is where I add the object to contextt

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Would be interested to know if you did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **using a Code Generation (EF5 ou EF6)**, it can be using HashSet in your entity class User...

Try to find the .tt files in you solution and change that line

```
this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new HashSet<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
```

to this

```
this.<#=code.Escape(navigationProperty)#> = new List<<#=typeMapper.GetTypeName(navigationProperty.ToEndMember.GetEntityType())#>>();
```

After that your entities classes will be rebuilt and work fine.